# How does Math.random() work like this?

Tags: javascript

So here we get a random number between 0 and 1 and round it down, so it always equals 0 right?

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random());
```

And then here we times it by 5. So surely 0 * 5 will always equal to 0?

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

So how does it return a number between 1 and 5?

Thanks

Comment: Look again. It's multiplied ***before*** it's being floored.

Comment: @Maxx the semantics of programming languages may not be obvious to people new to the field, and asking a clear question like this is a good way to learn.

Comment: "_And then here we times it by 5. So surely 0 * 5 will always equal to 0?_" - NO. Who told you it's `0*5`? `Math.random()*5` generates a number (double) between 0 - 4.

Comment: @progy_rock 0 - 4.999999…

Comment: I didn't realise Math.floor got called afterwards.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine yes, the argument expression is evaluated completely *before* the value is passed to the target function.

Comment: @deceze Of course! I'd say that was a typing error in a hurry :-P

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
```

is evaluated by first calling `Math.random()` and then multiplying that result by 5. That will be a number between 0 and 5 (possibly equal to zero, but always less than 5).

Only then will that result be passed to `Math.floor()`.

Parenthesized subexpressions are evaluated first, in general. In this case, it's a function call, but that's still a good "rule of thumb" to keep in mind. "Work from the inside out", which is kind-of backwards from how you're supposed to use silverware at a fancy dinner. I confess to never having figured out what to do with the utensils at the top of the plate however.

Comment: Just stop referencing the utensils at the top of the plate and the waiter will garbage collect them next time they come around.

Answer (score -2):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
```

.random() generate random number between 0 and 1 and .floor() rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer.

Comment: Downwards != to nearest

Answer (score -2):

```
var random = Math.round(Math.random() / (1/5))
```

This will give your number between 1-5.

Comment: ...which he already knows.   But wait a sec, what kind of rounding does `Math.round` do?  Nearest or celing?  Ceiling causes 1 to 5, nearest causes 0 to 5.  And why are you dividing 5 by 1?

Comment: By dividing a number n (which is between 0-1) by a fifth we obtain a number between 1 and 5, Example 0 / (1/5) = 0 and 1 / (1/5) = 5. The behaviour of Math.Round is as follows: positive number e.g. 1.5 is rounded to 2, then positive number 1.497236 is rounded to 1. Math.Round -> nearest integer